# How to restore previously selected list items using sessionStorage?

Tags: jquery, local-storage, session-storage

I'm working on a project in which I want to store selected list items (these items get a class of `active`) and on the next page load add this class to the selected items. There are 4 separate lists (with the same class) from among the selection can be made.

To achieve this task, I use sessionStorage. The question is how to store selected items, that on the next page load the right ones get `active` class?

I've tried to save item's text node to a sessionStorage and then, using `$.each()`, compare its value to a value of list items on a page. With no success though. I've made an attempt to save jQuery object of a selected item too, but in return I've got wrong data (just the last added item was in a fact jQuery object).

Here's located my code sample on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/kwiat_1990/pen/GWjjBd?editors=0100

```js
$(function() {
  // add/remove 'check icon' on the selected category
  $('.category__list').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var otherListItem = $('#author li:not(:first-child)');
    var firstListItem = $('#author li:first-child');
    var $this = $(this).not('.dropdown-header');

    if (firstListItem.hasClass('active')) {
      // mark/unmark clicked categories as chosen
      $this.hasClass('active') ? $this.removeClass('active') : $this.addClass('active');
      // when the first list item is eralier checked, any other selection uncheck the one on the first item
      if ($this.is(otherListItem)) {
        firstListItem.removeClass('active');
      }
    } else {
      $this.hasClass('active') ? $this.removeClass('active') : $this.addClass('active');
      // when the first item ('any' author) is checked, other selection on the list are unchecked
      if ($this.is(firstListItem)) {
        otherListItem.removeClass('active');
      }
    }

    // change dropdown text based on selection
    $('.dropdown button span:first-child').text(($(otherListItem).hasClass('active')) ? 'One or more selected' : 'Any');

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var categories = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('category')) || [];
    var checkedItem = $this.hasClass('active') ? $this.text() : '';
    categories.push(checkedItem);

    if (sessionStorage) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('category', JSON.stringify(categories));
    }
  });

  var lastCheckedItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('category'));
  var checkedItem;

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ececec;
}

.category {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.category__title {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.category__list {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.category__list li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.category__list li:not(.dropdown-header):hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.category__list li a {
  color: inherit;
}
.category__list li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
}
.category__list li.active:after {
  content: "X";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
}
.category__title, .category__list {
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.category .dropdown button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.category .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  float: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.category .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.category .dropdown-menu .active a,
.category .dropdown-menu .active a:hover,
.category .dropdown-menu .active a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.category .show .dropdown-toggle:after {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: .3em solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="category">
  <h3 class="category__title">Teams</h3>
  <ul class="category__list" id="category-team">
    <li><a href="#">Team Witten <span class="category__count">(1)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Team Helsinki <span class="category__count"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Team Louvain-La-Neuve</a> <span class="category__count">(2)</span></li>
  </ul>
  <h3 class="category__title">Subject</h3>
  <ul class="category__list" id="category-subject">
    <li><a href="#">Economics <span class="category__count"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Neuroscience <span class="category__count"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Psychology <span class="category__count"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <h3 class="category__title" id="category-year">Years</h3>
  <ul class="category__list">
    <li><a href="#">2016 <span class="category__count"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2017 <span class="category__count"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2018 <span class="category__count"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- dropdown -->
  <h3 class="category__title" id="category-author">Author</h3>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Any</span>
           </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu category__list" id="author">
      <li><a href="#">Any</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Team Witten</li>
      <li><a href="#">Author 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Author 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Author 3</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Team Helsinki</li>
      <li><a href="#">Author 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Author 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Author 3</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Team Louvain-La-Neuve</li>
      <li><a href="#">Author 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Author 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Author 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- end dropdown -->
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from your question and you CodePen is that you want to use sessionStorage and use the values from that to make the lists in next page with active class in it.

First, I do not know what are you storing in `sessionStorage` but it would be good if you are storing the `id` of those elements then it would be easier on other pages to make it active.

then, the data in the `sessionStorage` is in array form So, to access it first it would be better to store `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('category'));` in a variable and the access it like you use array with index number.

then in `js` file that you'll be including in the pages you want this feature try this or a simpler loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<{variable name of json}.length;i++){
  $('#{variable name of json}[i]').addClass( "active" );
}
```

For further information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: It's a though one. `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('category'));` is placed already in a variable `lastCheckedItems`. My code isn't complete due to problems with receiving data from `sessionStorage`. What I've changed is kind of a data structure I store in `sessionStorage`. Originally it was an array, but now I've decided to go with an object and based on`id` of each list, I split items inside created object. Then I use each loop to iterate through the object, firstly to find a right list and then one more time to find a right item. It doesn't work perfectly though.